# How to send an email on a button click with jquery, Parse, mailgun?

Tags: jquery, parsing, mailgun

I want a mail to be sent to the user when a button is clicked on a webpage. Is there a way to achieve this using  with jquery, Parse, mailgun? From Parse console I can invoke Parse.Cloud function using curl. But how to invoke the "sendMail" function on a button click inside $("#myButton").click()?

Comment: Make an ajax post to the server. Capture data on server, open curl, send data.

Comment: I have little idea about server side programming. If you can point me to an example that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this and here is how I did it.

[http://www.chilifunfactory.com/chili-blog/send-emails-with-parse-and-mailgun](http://www.chilifunfactory.com/chili-blog/send-emails-with-parse-and-mailgun.)

You will need to write some cloud code in Parse.

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("sendMail", function(request, response) {
        var mailgun = require('mailgun');

        mailgun.initialize('your domain.mailgun.org', 'key-your-key');
        mailgun.sendEmail({
                to: request.params.toEmail,
                from: request.params.fromEmail,
                subject: request.params.subject,
                text: request.params.comments
            }, 
            {
                success: function(httpResponse) {
                    console.log(httpResponse);
                    response.success("Email sent!");
            },
                error: function(httpResponse) {
                console.error(httpResponse);
                response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
            }
        });
    });
```

Then in your javascript you can simply call the method and send your email

```
    Parse.Cloud.run('sendMail', 
       { 
           "toEmail": "customer service email address",
           "fromEmail": "customer email address,
           "subject": "Subject",
           "comments": "Customer Comments"
       }, 
       {
           success: function(result) {
               alert(result); 
           },
           error: function(error) {
               alert(error.message);
           }
        }
    );
```